# Is there an aircraft hostel in Canada or USA?

Tags: usa, accommodation, canada, hostels, north-america

Today we talked about hostels in funny locations, e.g. old prisons. Since I'm going to Canada and USA very soon, I would really like to spend some nights in an old aircraft that is now a hostel. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Not in North America, but I wish this had been open when I was in Stockholm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbohostel

Comment: I wonder if this guy is on VRBO: http://www.airplanehome.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, some time, so I've found the three best candidates that I can, although not all are entire planes...or in planes...

1. First up, we have the [Floridian Fly-in home + aircraft](http://www.airbnb.com/rooms/60058) - you can rent a home, which comes WITH a plane and pool!

   [image: Fly-in home + plane]
2. [Next, Hughes' Cosmic Muffin.](http://www.planeboats.com/Other%20Pages/Photos/index/boat%20index.html)  This is a plane that was owned by Howard Hughes, now converted into ... a house boat.  The website is horrific, but the photos are really interesting.

   [image]
3. Finally, some have their Malibu Beach House, but here we have the [Malibu Wing House](http://www.studioea.com/projects/residential/wing_house/index.php).  About 4.5 million parts recycled from an old Boeing 747 were re-purposed to create this environmentally sustainable home, and the front portion of the fuselage and the upper first class cabin deck are used to shelter the guest house.

   [image]

As for a hostel, no, sorry, no luck so far aside from the one in Stockholm, but will keep looking!

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest you can get would be a "Helicopter" cottage at [Winvian](http://www.winvian.com/cottages.asp), though it's a bit on the expensive side.

There are plenty of treehouses and Wigwams though. :)